# OpenSSL Error[0]: error:140360B2:SSL routines:ACCEPT_SR_CERT:no certificate returned | gmqtt with tls/ssl python

Tags: python, python-3.x, openssl, ssl-certificate, mqtt

I am trying to implement ssl/tsl in gmqtt but encountered error:

```
OpenSSL Error[0]: error:140360B2:SSL routines:ACCEPT_SR_CERT:no certificate returned.
```

Followed [these steps](https://www.engineersgarage.com/tutorials/secure-client-server-communication-over-tls-security-protocol-using-mosquitto-broker-iot-part-42/) to generate certificates.

Copied all the files from local system to docker, as the app is ran by docker.

```
[dockerfile (mosquitto)]

COPY ./certs/mosquitto_server.crt /mosquitto_server.crt
COPY ./certs/ca.crt /ca.crt
COPY ./certs/mosquitto_server.key /mosquitto_server.key

[mosquitto.conf]
cafile /ca.crt
certfile /mosquitto_server.crt
keyfile /mosquitto_server.key
tls_version tlsv1.2
require_certificate true
```

code implementation:

```
sub_client = MQTTClient("test")
ssl_context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
ssl_context.load_cert_chain('/mosquitto_client.crt', keyfile='/mosquitto_client.key', password= "1111")
self.assign_callbacks_to_client(sub_client)
logging.info("connecting")
await sub_client.connect(host=config.MQTT_HOST, port=int(config.MQTT_PORT), ssl=ssl_context)
```

Raised one [issue on github](https://github.com/wialon/gmqtt/issues/122) too (Revolved most of the issues but now encountered `error:140360B2:SSL routines:ACCEPT_SR_CERT:no certificate returned`)

Comment: You've added nothing else to the `mosquitto.conf` no `port` or `listener` entry? Also have you tried connecting with `openssl s_client`?

Comment: Also have you rolled your own mosquitto Dockerfile or are you just extending the official eclipse build?

Comment: @hardillb there is a main docker file and extending the eclipse one in mosquitto docker

Comment: @hardillb I have tried with port and listener it's not working.
will try openssl s_client

Comment: @hardillb I tried with openssl s_client, encountered this error : 
       
-  Verification error: self signed certificate
-  Can't use SSL_get_servername

-23564:error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure:../openssl-1.1.1g/ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1543:SSL alert number 40